# How do I create a responsive background image?

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I'm trying to make my background images responsive and it seems to work ok on desktops, but it's messing up on mobile. Specifically the iPhone 6 Plus according to my boss.

Here's my code:

```
min-height: 500px; /* different height for different sections */
background: url('../img/bg-image.png') center center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
color: #fff;
padding: 50px 0;
```

The site is here so you can test it out:

http://www.breadtrails.com

Comment: Looks good on my end in inspect element device mode, maybe a caching issue. Have you got another iP6+ on hand to test?

Comment: Thanks man, unfortunately I don't have an iPhone, but my boss does. Here's the screen shots he sent me:

Comment: I see no screenshots! :-P

Comment: Sorry, I sent the comment to soon haha. I'm uploading it to imgur

Comment: Well, imgur's a fail, but the screen shot shows the background image zoomed in and distorted. Idk why

Comment: edit the question and attach the pic here

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue using the iOS emulator on Mac. I know this isn't the answer to your question - but it might be worth providing a different background on mobile devices. It will make a decent change to the data needed to load over a mobile network.

Comment: Hey guys, I actually fixed the issue yesterday iOS doesn't support background-attachment:fixed. Thanks for all the help!